# aura:if Determined by Custom Label Value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, customlabel

Is it possible to use a custom label (set to "true" or "false") to drive an `aura:if` condition? For instance, I want to display a banner message about upcoming maintenance. If my custom label was "MaintenanceMessage" and the value was set to "true", would this condition work?

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!$Label.c.MaintenanceMessage} == true">
    <c:MaintenanceBannerComponent />
</aura:if>
```

And then setting the label to "false" to no longer show the message?

Comment: Yes, it is possible? You can also use render:if or something similar, have you tried?

Comment: No, I haven't used `render:if`. I'll check into that, too.

Comment: @glls [render:if](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:renderIf/documentation) is deprecated.

Comment: Sheitz, oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its possible to use a custom label in [`aura:if`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:if/documentation), you just have minor syntax error, following would work:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!$Label.c.FirstLabel == 'your value'}">
    <c:MaintenanceBannerComponent />
</aura:if>
```

Better place would be to use a custom setting instead of a label, as its much easier to manage.

Comment: +1 , I copied from your comment :)

Comment: Thanks @Raul. I'm a bit new to this but can I reference a custom setting similar to how I'd reference a custom label?

Comment: @MattSmith: if that is a hierarchial custom setting, it would be similar. Otherwise you may have to pass the value from apex class.

Answer (score 2):

As Raul, suggested you can use something like

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!$Label.c.MaintenanceMessage} == 'true'}">
    <c:MaintenanceBannerComponent />
</aura:if>
```

as `true` would be a `String` instead of `boolean`
It would work, but would like to point few points.

1) Its a Custom Label , which accepts free text, thus there is big chance that a human mess things up and your logic starts breaking.

2) Also, you have consider about Multi-Language, as custom labels get translated, true /false in some other language would cause your logic to break.

A better way would be to use custom settings or metadata types.